# Importing multilevel indexed cvs data with pandas 0.13

Tags: python, csv, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to import CSV data with multi-indexed columns using Pandas 0.13 `read_csv`. The import is successful, but the resulting multi-index for the columns is surprising and not useful for me.

```
employment=pd.read_csv('./data/spanish/employment1976-1987thousands.csv', index_col=0,header=[7,8])
```

**employment1976-1987thousands.csv**:

```
4.- Resultados provinciales
    Encuesta  Poblacion Activa. Principales Resultados

Activos por provincia y grupo  edad (4).
Unidas:miles  personas


,Alava,,,,Albacete,,,,Alicante,,,,Almeria,,,,Asturias,,,,Avila,,,,Badajoz,,,,Balears (Illes),,,,Barcelona,,,,Burgos,,,,Caceres,,,,Cadiz,,,,Cantabria,,,,Castellon  la Plana,,,,Ciudad Real,,,,Cordoba,,,,Coruna (A),,,,Cuenca,,,,Girona,,,,Granada,,,,Guadalajara,,,,Guipuzcoa,,,,Huelva,,,,Huesca,,,,Jaen,,,,Leon,,,,Lleida,,,,Lugo,,,,Madrid,,,,Malaga,,,,Murcia,,,,Navarra,,,,Orense,,,,Palencia,,,,Palmas (Las),,,,Pontevedra,,,,Rioja (La),,,,Salamanca,,,,Santa Cruz  Tenerife,,,,Segovia,,,,Sevilla,,,,Soria,,,,Tarragona,,,,Teruel,,,,Toledo,,,,Valencia,,,,Valladolid,,,,Vizcaya,,,,Zamora,,,,Zaragoza,,,,Ceuta y Melilla,,,,
, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo, 16  19 yo, 20  24 yo, 25  54 yo, 55 y over yo,
1976TIII,"8.9","11.6","60.4","11.8","16.4","14.4","65.2","14.9","47.9","49.9","246.0","60.1","20.5","14.3","88.9","11.2","34.5","42.5","278.0","91.3","6.6","7.2","41.5","13.3","25.3","22.8","135.3","37.5","19.8","24.4","153.0","43.0","166.8","203.7","1079.0","230.7","14.1","16.4","86.0","23.8","17.0","18.3","86.6","28.6","31.0","38.7","180.4","29.8","15.3","19.2","120.6","30.4","19.9","15.3","104.2","23.4","19.7","19.5","97.5","29.7","28.0","23.9","140.5","30.1","29.1","46.1","263.8","70.0","8.9","6.2","45.7","14.6","19.7","19.7","123.0","35.3","26.8","22.5","141.0","36.2","4.8","6.0","33.1","13.4","23.1","31.6","174.5","33.8","11.9","14.3","83.8","18.8","7.0","9.3","50.3","20.0","22.4","23.4","125.8","28.6","22.7","21.6","143.1","50.9","12.5","13.7","89.5","33.2","14.3","14.7","134.0","54.7","136.6","207.5","1067.6","218.6","34.7","41.1","196.4","38.4","37.2","35.0","200.5","46.1","15.6","23.8","111.6","30.7","14.0","16.8","120.2","74.9","5.7","6.4","39.2","8.0","24.5","25.6","135.3","27.1","36.4","39.4","246.1","74.0","10.2","11.3","63.9","13.4","10.5","11.0","74.1","19.6","19.3","23.9","140.3","31.7","5.5","6.0","35.6","11.3","55.2","55.6","262.5","68.1","3.1","3.2","24.4","5.4","21.8","18.4","116.7","37.1","4.6","3.4","37.3","12.0","20.3","16.7","102.2","23.1","73.5","85.5","454.6","101.5","19.2","23.4","90.7","20.5","41.3","54.7","272.2","57.0","6.0","7.1","56.5","28.9","29.2","32.1","192.7","49.8","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1976TIV,"8.7","11.7","60.8","11.4","14.4","13.6","63.3","14.5","49.1","50.6","244.9","54.2","19.0","16.9","86.8","11.4","33.2","42.3","271.8","86.0","5.8","7.5","40.3","13.9","25.1","24.7","132.7","38.4","18.8","23.4","151.8","43.9","172.2","201.7","1070.7","228.1","11.1","15.7","82.5","21.1","16.4","18.0","89.2","26.6","32.6","40.0","176.5","30.5","15.8","18.1","121.3","30.2","19.0","17.3","106.3","24.1","19.9","19.0","101.7","26.9","25.3","22.3","142.7","28.9","30.0","42.4","267.6","70.1","7.3","7.0","44.4","13.0","17.8","21.4","122.8","34.0","28.4","21.6","140.5","36.8","4.7","6.6","32.6","10.8","24.8","32.7","177.2","32.3","11.9","12.5","85.4","20.5","6.9","8.5","48.8","19.9","22.4","22.1","127.6","25.1","18.5","21.1","137.8","48.7","12.4","11.1","84.9","31.5","13.6","15.6","132.7","52.0","144.0","202.3","1054.0","222.5","35.6","40.1","194.1","37.5","36.7","34.7","203.8","47.1","15.6","23.6","114.3","31.3","14.0","15.9","118.3","76.7","5.5","7.3","36.9","9.3","25.5","25.1","138.7","26.8","34.8","42.9","250.3","74.9","9.9","11.8","62.8","14.0","10.0","13.2","74.5","19.2","19.5","24.2","142.7","31.0","4.0","5.9","35.5","12.0","55.0","56.7","264.7","63.3","2.8","3.5","23.9","5.1","20.0","21.6","116.4","34.9","4.5","3.7","36.5","12.1","21.1","17.6","100.6","25.7","74.6","87.5","455.5","102.1","18.9","22.9","90.0","21.6","40.2","57.1","273.9","58.5","5.6","8.3","57.6","23.9","28.3","31.4","192.2","46.4","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1977TI,"9.2","11.8","59.9","11.2","14.2","13.2","65.9","14.7","48.2","50.4","251.1","50.8","17.8","15.4","86.5","11.8","30.6","42.9","272.6","84.1","5.8","7.4","37.2","12.8","24.1","22.8","131.3","38.2","17.8","23.5","151.1","42.5","168.1","200.4","1077.2","223.3","11.6","12.8","80.9","17.6","14.4","16.4","88.2","23.9","34.5","37.5","176.3","30.8","15.2","19.7","121.3","31.6","18.4","19.4","107.4","24.7","20.0","18.1","98.3","26.6","24.9","23.6","150.7","27.5","29.5","40.3","267.4","70.5","5.6","7.5","44.2","12.8","17.1","21.1","122.8","33.6","29.6","23.3","142.1","37.9","4.6","5.5","33.7","11.2","23.5","30.4","175.2","32.8","12.0","12.7","84.8","21.3","7.3","9.3","46.6","17.8","30.2","26.0","147.1","25.2","15.9","22.7","133.2","45.1","12.8","12.1","84.3","28.0","12.4","16.5","131.2","55.6","150.9","202.9","1065.4","223.7","36.6","44.0","194.3","39.9","36.7","31.5","196.7","45.7","14.8","22.5","115.1","29.4","11.7","17.2","114.2","75.8","5.0","7.7","38.0","9.4","24.0","26.8","143.5","27.0","35.3","43.0","247.4","73.5","9.7","12.1","61.6","13.3","9.5","11.9","73.9","18.9","20.4","26.7","143.0","31.6","4.0","5.0","35.5","12.3","52.3","58.0","266.0","62.5","2.6","2.7","24.2","6.0","17.3","21.0","113.0","33.3","4.5","5.2","33.8","10.6","18.7","18.8","98.3","24.8","77.4","87.6","446.6","100.3","20.5","23.4","90.2","20.4","38.7","50.7","277.6","57.3","6.4","8.7","60.1","21.5","28.6","31.0","194.8","45.7","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1977TII,"8.4","11.6","62.6","10.9","14.9","11.7","67.8","13.9","46.8","49.1","254.9","49.2","16.9","13.4","90.2","12.9","28.8","41.3","270.5","85.0","5.3","7.9","37.5","12.4","25.0","24.6","129.5","38.0","15.4","24.8","154.7","44.5","167.5","205.0","1078.8","221.8","11.2","13.7","80.7","19.4","12.9","15.6","88.3","24.2","33.8","36.0","181.0","28.8","14.3","19.5","119.0","31.6","17.4","17.4","104.0","23.3","19.9","20.4","95.6","27.0","24.9","22.4","145.3","27.7","27.7","40.1","271.3","70.8","6.6","7.8","42.3","13.0","17.9","20.1","127.1","32.6","28.0","22.6","140.1","37.0","4.2","6.0","32.4","11.4","24.1","30.9","179.1","31.9","11.5","12.6","82.5","22.7","6.1","9.7","46.9","18.3","22.6","20.4","124.9","24.8","16.6","19.1","134.3","47.8","10.7","11.9","83.6","29.6","12.3","16.6","130.4","52.9","143.9","199.9","1068.7","220.5","38.4","39.5","197.7","40.6","36.6","36.3","201.2","43.8","13.8","22.0","116.0","29.2","11.7","17.4","116.8","71.3","5.4","6.9","37.0","9.8","24.5","26.6","142.1","27.7","35.5","41.8","243.9","71.6","9.6","12.0","62.5","13.2","8.4","12.8","76.9","19.0","19.6","25.0","143.2","31.5","3.7","5.5","34.5","11.7","54.3","58.4","262.6","58.6","2.9","2.9","23.7","7.1","16.1","19.9","115.2","32.5","3.7","5.4","32.9","10.2","17.1","19.0","99.0","28.1","74.6","91.3","449.2","103.7","19.1","24.3","89.9","20.0","41.4","49.2","275.9","58.8","5.5","8.4","58.5","19.9","29.4","31.2","195.6","46.2","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1977TIII,"7.8","12.4","63.1","12.0","16.2","12.3","67.2","14.8","49.5","51.0","256.4","49.3","17.3","15.0","87.0","13.6","30.8","42.9","272.8","85.9","6.8","7.3","37.4","12.9","26.1","25.5","132.7","37.1","16.6","27.1","155.7","43.2","172.5","204.2","1087.1","217.4","11.8","14.1","81.8","22.4","14.2","14.7","87.3","25.4","36.8","34.0","183.2","30.3","13.5","20.0","119.2","30.2","17.3","16.8","101.5","23.9","22.3","21.0","96.8","25.5","24.2","19.7","143.2","27.7","27.6","40.5","268.1","69.4","7.3","6.8","44.6","12.7","19.4","21.3","124.4","33.8","26.6","23.1","142.2","36.4","4.7","6.0","32.4","12.2","25.3","30.5","175.5","32.0","11.6","13.0","83.1","20.7","5.4","10.6","46.3","19.2","21.7","19.5","124.8","25.6","18.1","21.3","138.7","46.5","11.7","12.6","85.8","29.1","12.8","17.8","128.2","55.6","151.4","202.8","1060.0","214.1","38.5","40.3","197.9","41.0","38.3","39.3","201.9","45.6","17.0","23.1","114.8","30.9","13.3","16.5","115.4","70.9","5.4","7.7","37.5","10.0","28.0","29.4","141.3","26.3","34.1","39.4","247.7","71.6","10.0","12.6","63.3","13.3","11.8","14.2","76.3","17.7","17.6","24.1","145.6","33.5","4.5","4.7","36.6","12.0","53.9","61.2","259.6","61.9","3.1","3.6","23.3","7.3","15.8","19.9","117.0","33.9","4.2","5.8","33.4","11.2","16.7","21.4","100.0","28.5","76.8","91.8","446.7","104.8","19.8","22.1","92.0","21.3","39.6","49.0","281.1","58.8","7.0","8.6","57.6","19.6","29.6","33.4","196.0","46.5","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1977TIV,"7.3","11.4","63.5","12.3","14.3","13.2","67.9","15.4","47.7","51.8","254.4","52.1","17.0","14.9","84.6","14.3","28.8","41.9","276.1","81.3","7.4","6.0","37.0","11.8","27.8","25.6","131.3","36.6","16.0","25.6","154.9","41.1","168.2","209.1","1103.8","211.6","12.0","14.1","82.8","22.0","14.1","15.3","88.0","25.4","37.8","36.1","180.3","33.5","13.5","18.8","121.2","30.3","17.8","16.7","104.8","23.8","21.3","21.6","95.3","25.9","24.2","21.8","144.3","28.4","26.7","42.4","265.4","68.8","8.4","7.3","45.8","11.9","17.7","20.7","119.8","34.5","25.1","22.6","141.7","38.9","4.2","6.9","30.9","12.2","24.5","33.0","170.2","30.6","12.1","11.3","82.1","21.1","4.9","9.9","46.1","19.2","23.5","20.6","130.6","26.9","13.7","20.4","136.1","46.2","10.3","12.9","85.3","27.4","12.3","18.2","124.5","58.5","157.1","201.3","1065.5","216.1","37.9","46.3","200.2","41.0","37.1","39.1","206.7","43.2","15.9","22.7","115.1","30.3","13.8","18.6","122.6","66.9","6.0","8.1","37.8","10.3","27.4","28.2","142.2","26.9","37.2","37.2","246.4","70.7","9.7","11.6","62.9","15.9","11.8","13.9","76.8","18.2","19.1","23.9","149.8","31.2","3.5","4.2","37.0","11.0","56.0","63.7","268.5","59.5","2.9","3.2","23.0","7.5","14.8","19.4","119.5","33.6","4.3","6.2","33.6","10.8","16.3","19.7","98.3","29.8","75.8","96.9","451.4","108.1","20.9","22.5","92.9","21.9","38.5","50.5","284.0","56.7","6.7","7.4","59.2","18.1","31.2","36.4","197.3","49.4","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1978TI,"7.5","12.1","62.4","12.5","14.7","13.3","67.6","14.9","46.3","54.8","253.8","53.0","18.0","14.5","84.9","14.7","28.5","42.6","275.7","80.1","7.7","6.5","36.9","11.2","27.5","27.2","131.3","35.3","16.4","24.3","155.2","41.3","166.6","205.0","1110.7","218.2","12.3","13.5","82.9","23.5","13.7","14.4","84.7","25.2","36.2","37.9","185.9","33.7","13.6","20.4","123.4","32.4","16.8","17.0","104.3","26.9","20.0","20.8","95.7","26.0","24.6","24.1","146.6","28.7","26.8","38.2","266.8","69.2","8.2","6.9","44.6","12.4","17.1","21.9","119.9","35.7","26.4","25.2","142.7","38.3","3.6","5.5","32.0","11.7","24.9","34.4","167.9","31.3","12.5","11.4","81.2","20.9","4.2","9.3","47.1","17.5","25.6","22.0","140.5","27.0","12.0","20.6","135.0","44.7","10.4","12.5","84.1","25.2","13.8","17.9","125.6","51.5","148.4","209.1","1065.4","211.7","36.1","43.7","202.7","41.0","34.1","38.5","203.2","44.7","15.4","20.6","116.1","29.6","13.3","15.8","121.0","67.3","5.9","7.5","37.2","9.6","26.9","31.0","144.8","28.9","33.7","40.9","240.5","71.0","8.6","12.2","61.3","14.9","9.9","14.3","77.9","17.3","21.5","25.0","151.1","32.4","3.5","4.8","34.6","9.6","49.5","64.0","267.6","55.5","2.5","3.4","22.5","7.4","15.8","20.2","114.1","32.6","3.6","6.5","31.5","10.8","16.7","20.8","95.3","30.4","78.0","95.5","452.3","109.7","20.7","21.0","94.8","20.0","39.0","51.1","291.2","53.4","8.1","7.5","59.5","17.2","28.9","37.3","192.4","47.9","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1978TII,"6.8","12.1","62.9","13.4","13.3","12.3","65.9","16.9","44.6","55.6","251.2","54.9","17.4","16.5","86.3","13.6","25.8","44.3","278.2","82.0","7.7","6.2","37.4","12.1","25.7","24.9","134.1","35.9","17.5","24.8","153.2","40.7","166.0","211.2","1105.6","216.2","11.9","13.7","83.1","21.8","15.6","15.3","83.1","23.2","34.6","34.5","185.9","34.2","13.0","20.2","122.6","33.7","16.5","15.4","100.0","26.1","19.0","20.6","97.2","28.3","22.9","24.0","137.6","28.7","25.5","37.5","264.8","67.9","8.2","6.7","43.7","12.1","17.2","21.5","122.9","34.9","23.2","28.9","146.7","37.7","3.3","5.0","31.1","11.7","25.6","36.3","165.8","31.5","12.0","12.2","81.8","18.8","4.8","10.1","45.2","16.7","21.7","19.8","122.3","24.8","12.1","20.7","135.3","47.3","9.5","13.9","85.2","26.2","14.2","15.8","124.2","52.1","139.2","212.8","1070.2","218.2","32.6","41.5","198.7","41.2","34.5","39.5","203.7","43.7","14.8","22.0","117.0","30.6","12.8","15.7","120.7","66.1","5.3","6.8","37.8","10.2","27.2","30.7","146.9","28.6","34.0","42.1","242.7","69.7","8.1","11.5","62.3","15.0","9.1","14.7","76.8","17.3","21.1","25.3","146.8","31.7","3.5","5.2","34.9","9.7","52.2","59.5","271.2","58.8","2.5","3.2","22.2","7.0","16.3","18.0","115.8","32.9","4.1","6.6","31.3","10.6","17.5","20.0","98.7","28.8","77.2","88.3","456.5","106.0","17.4","21.4","95.2","21.4","38.4","53.5","291.8","55.0","6.9","6.2","56.9","18.8","28.8","37.1","193.2","49.6","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1978TIII,"7.5","11.6","62.6","13.9","14.2","13.3","67.9","16.2","48.1","56.3","249.3","58.0","17.6","16.1","84.4","13.3","27.3","46.0","278.0","83.5","7.7","6.3","38.7","12.0","26.7","27.7","131.7","35.3","18.4","27.3","154.3","41.7","168.9","216.3","1106.4","212.9","12.6","16.4","80.6","22.4","16.4","16.4","84.7","23.0","32.4","39.8","192.6","34.8","13.0","20.5","121.5","35.0","18.9","15.9","93.8","24.9","20.7","21.1","95.2","27.4","22.3","25.5","136.1","31.6","24.8","38.5","259.4","68.1","8.5","6.3","43.4","11.6","18.3","23.2","122.7","35.3","26.9","26.8","150.7","35.2","4.0","6.0","29.5","11.3","28.5","38.2","163.0","31.6","11.6","12.7","84.0","17.8","5.0","8.9","47.1","16.7","26.6","21.9","124.6","23.5","15.3","23.2","138.2","50.0","9.2","16.8","87.8","27.0","10.8","16.1","127.0","49.8","137.8","216.9","1067.4","216.2","34.4","40.4","197.3","44.5","38.5","42.0","207.1","45.5","16.9","23.2","115.1","31.2","13.0","14.5","120.5","69.7","5.1","7.3","37.5","10.7","30.5","29.9","143.8","28.2","31.8","38.7","242.2","70.3","9.4","12.3","62.0","14.4","9.7","15.1","78.2","16.2","19.5","26.2","148.1","30.1","4.4","5.8","35.8","9.3","51.7","55.9","267.2","57.4","2.3","3.4","21.6","6.2","17.6","19.0","117.7","30.9","4.5","6.3","32.9","11.4","18.2","20.7","98.7","29.3","72.9","86.4","459.6","100.4","16.1","21.8","97.3","22.3","33.3","51.9","292.3","56.2","6.4","9.0","53.4","18.6","30.2","36.3","191.5","48.2","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1978TIV,"8.2","11.2","62.3","13.9","13.4","13.7","66.1","17.5","49.0","56.6","256.6","61.2","16.6","15.8","83.5","13.1","29.6","46.8","275.8","81.8","7.0","5.4","36.6","13.0","26.0","24.5","135.2","36.4","19.6","26.2","151.6","40.4","171.2","210.5","1106.6","222.1","12.0","16.2","79.5","22.1","17.1","17.8","83.7","22.6","31.8","41.6","197.7","35.3","12.6","19.5","123.6","35.8","20.9","15.9","96.3","25.5","19.5","21.3","94.9","23.8","24.0","27.3","136.7","32.3","25.2","39.1","263.4","66.9","8.0","6.8","44.4","11.8","17.5","21.3","120.2","34.7","26.0","27.1","150.5","33.5","4.3","5.8","29.4","10.5","25.6","36.6","165.6","30.9","13.3","12.3","83.8","19.0","3.4","8.3","48.4","15.9","24.5","20.6","124.8","24.3","11.9","19.8","134.1","47.8","8.4","16.2","84.3","28.0","9.7","14.7","126.0","51.8","133.4","208.8","1059.9","214.5","33.2","39.6","194.8","43.5","37.7","42.5","208.3","44.8","17.0","25.3","114.2","31.5","13.7","15.4","117.6","64.5","5.7","7.4","37.6","10.2","30.6","31.8","148.7","28.4","32.3","41.7","243.5","71.2","7.8","13.0","61.8","15.3","9.6","14.8","81.0","19.0","21.0","26.8","146.4","31.0","3.6","6.1","35.6","9.0","49.0","59.3","266.6","57.6","2.0","3.4","22.1","5.5","18.1","19.6","118.8","30.5","4.4","5.6","33.0","10.2","19.0","22.2","98.6","30.2","72.6","88.4","468.3","104.1","16.8","24.5","97.1","21.2","31.2","56.5","291.6","54.7","5.5","8.4","54.9","19.4","30.2","37.0","196.2","48.4","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1979TI,"7.9","10.2","64.0","12.4","13.1","12.5","66.6","18.0","49.5","61.4","262.2","59.4","15.7","16.6","86.4","11.9","28.3","46.7","277.9","82.2","6.3","5.4","37.2","12.4","23.9","26.4","132.9","35.5","18.0","25.1","155.0","41.2","166.6","212.1","1117.4","224.5","12.1","15.6","84.7","20.1","16.0","15.8","82.7","21.0","33.5","43.6","198.6","34.8","12.2","19.4","123.0","35.7","19.2","16.7","101.4","26.1","18.3","17.5","94.8","21.9","25.3","28.7","142.2","32.5","28.4","36.4","261.9","66.3","8.6","6.8","42.8","12.3","18.6","23.9","119.2","34.0","25.4","27.2","151.8","33.1","3.4","6.8","29.5","9.8","24.2","36.9","166.6","30.9","10.9","12.5","84.2","19.0","4.0","8.4","49.3","14.0","29.0","23.1","146.2","25.7","12.9","21.1","131.0","46.9","7.9","16.8","81.5","28.3","9.7","14.1","123.4","52.0","130.5","205.4","1072.2","215.8","36.2","43.2","196.8","46.4","37.5","41.2","203.9","43.8","16.6","24.0","114.4","29.4","12.5","15.5","119.4","59.4","5.2","6.2","38.3","9.4","28.0","35.0","150.9","30.7","32.9","42.9","241.0","69.6","7.7","12.0","59.6","14.6","8.7","14.3","80.4","19.6","21.8","25.8","149.5","31.2","3.7","6.1","34.7","9.1","47.6","56.8","269.6","55.6","2.2","3.4","21.9","4.9","18.7","21.7","117.9","29.5","4.0","6.3","32.6","9.5","18.7","21.7","96.0","28.4","71.6","88.2","468.8","106.4","18.1","25.6","95.5","20.6","30.4","57.1","291.6","54.0","5.7","8.3","54.6","18.1","27.4","40.6","194.5","45.9","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
1979TII,"7.7","11.0","64.7","12.5","12.9","12.3","65.2","17.5","50.1","60.6","267.1","58.3","12.5","15.8","88.0","11.2","26.1","44.6","276.0","83.1","6.0","6.1","36.3","13.3","27.2","24.4","132.4","35.5","18.1","27.5","154.2","41.7","155.8","214.8","1111.6","218.4","11.6","17.2","85.3","20.4","15.3","18.0","81.3","20.9","30.5","39.3","199.7","31.9","12.5","19.5","125.5","35.6","17.7","15.9","98.8","25.5","19.5","20.0","94.3","23.4","22.0","27.7","139.7","30.9","28.9","37.0","261.7","70.4","7.7","7.2","40.5","12.3","16.0","25.6","119.7","33.5","26.7","26.8","150.6","34.4","3.4","6.5","29.9","9.2","21.6","37.5","170.1","31.9","11.0","11.8","84.5","20.0","4.7","8.1","53.2","13.3","25.5","22.0","125.1","24.1","12.6","23.3","132.7","46.1","8.2","15.1","82.7","29.0","8.5","14.4","126.3","50.0","118.0","206.1","1077.0","215.0","39.5","42.4","192.8","44.4","38.8","41.2","202.1","45.4","17.4","24.5","115.5","30.8","13.1","14.1","118.4","63.2","5.3","7.6","38.7","8.2","26.7","33.8","154.0","29.9","32.8","41.5","245.2","64.9","7.3","12.1","61.0","15.2","8.3","12.9","79.2","21.0","19.4","26.4","145.3","28.8","3.8","6.1","35.7","9.9","50.0","57.1","264.9","57.9","1.9","3.1","21.7","5.2","17.8","21.5","121.4","28.1","4.0","5.5","29.8","11.2","17.4","19.8","95.1","26.8","75.4","86.7","465.3","104.2","15.1","22.0","97.8","23.2","33.8","56.5","292.6","51.5","4.8","9.3","53.3","18.2","26.1","40.0","196.8","45.3","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0",
```

The resulting columns index is

```
Alava                  16  19 yo          
Unnamed: 2_level_0     20  24 yo          
Unnamed: 3_level_0     25  54 yo          
Unnamed: 4_level_0     55 y over yo       
Albacete               16  19 yo          
Unnamed: 6_level_0     20  24 yo          
Unnamed: 7_level_0     25  54 yo          
Unnamed: 8_level_0     55 y over yo
```

and I was hoping to get it in the form

```
Alava    16  19 yo          
Alava    20  24 yo          
Alava    25  54 yo          
Alava    55 y over yo       
Albacete     16  19 yo          
Albacete     20  24 yo          
Albacete     25  54 yo          
Albacete    55 y over yo
```

Comment: your first level is 'sparse'. you need a repeated field name for the header line 7, e.g. something like: 'Alva,Alva,Alva,Alva,Albacete,Albacet.....'. It is very ambiguous to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to convert after the fact:

```
In [42]: data = """A,,B,
   ....: 1,2,1,2
   ....: 1,2,3,4
   ....: 5,6,7,8
   ....: """

In [43]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),header=[0,1],index_col=None)

In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
   A  Unnamed: 1_level_0  B  Unnamed: 3_level_0
   1                   2  1                   2
0  1                   2  3                   4
1  5                   6  7                   8

[2 rows x 4 columns]

In [45]: df.columns = unsparsify_labels(df.columns)

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
   A     B   
   1  2  1  2
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8

[2 rows x 4 columns]

In [40]: def unsparsify_labels(index):
   ....:     new_labels = []
   ....:     for label in index.values:
   ....:         if label[0].startswith('Unnamed'):
   ....:             label = list(label)
   ....:             label[0] = ll
   ....:             label = tuple(label)
   ....:         else:
   ....:             ll = label[0]
   ....:         new_labels.append(label)
   ....:     return MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_labels)
   ....:
```

Comment: I saw the very old [ENH: unsparsify multi-index column labels ](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5668) issue about this. I don't if this is already a feature of pandas. But this little helper function is very helpful.